# glTexImage2D does not render the picture

Tags: android, opengl-es

Why does this not display me the graphic? All I get is a white square. The picture is 512x512.

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl) {  

      imageData = ByteBuffer.allocate(mPicture512.length).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    imageData.put(mPicture512);  
    imageData.position(0); 
    // generate one texture pointer 
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array 
//Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(mContext);

//bitmap.getPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height)

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); 
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0,GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_BYTE, imageData);
```

ps. I know I could this the following and it works, but since this is a performance critical app I do not want the overhead of first creating the bitmap.

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem what that I was loading a bitmap PNG which has headers and not a raw picture.

Comment: So how can i generate a raw image picture. I found that the pictures i generated with gimp always can't loaded by opengl. But some pictures found on the net can be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

`glTexParameter` modifies a per-texture state. Your min/mag filter setup is called before you bind the texture, so it has no effect on your texture.

Therefore your texture is still using the default mipmapping for the min filter, and will not display correctly.

Comment: i put the min_mag_filter below and I still only get a white square

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you upload the image to OpenGL in a different manner?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(activity.getAssets().open(fileName));

GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: this works but since this is a performance critical app I do not want the burden of creating a bitmap and then calling GLUtils.texImage2d().
That is way I want to use this method which only needs a buffer:
gl.glTexImage2D()